# Circle On Sphere

Tags: parametric, spherical-trigonometry

[image: enter myproblem]

Sorry if this sounds too silly but  my math skills are very poor and I just need this problem fixed. 
I made this graphic with geogebra 3D and it was quite easy there but I don't know how to write the equations for this.
In the image you can see:

- Sphere with radius 1.
- Point $B$ on the sphere with spherical coordinates.
- Point $C$ on the sphere with spherical coordinates.
- $\alpha$ is the angle between $B$ and $C$.
- Circle $d$ on the sphere from segment $b$ through point $C$.
- $G$ and $D$ are points on that circle.
- $\theta$ is the angle between $C$ and $D$ from the center of the circle.

What I want is an equation that, given and Initial Point ($B$), and $\alpha$ angle, gives me points on the circle $d$ ( like $C$, $G$ or $D$) with $\theta$ as a parameter.
And if possible in spherical coordinates... 
Thanks

Comment: There are multiple ways to proceed, and the "preferred" strategy may depend on your intended purpose for these formulas. Could you please say a little about where the question comes from? Also, spherical coordinates are often denoted $\theta$ and $\phi$; there's no universal convention on which means what (longitude, latitude, or co-latitude), and your suggested parameter $\theta$ is presumably not the spherical coordinate $\theta$?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the interest. I am trying to do a little Script in a program called Zbrush. It's a 3d modeling software. What I want to do is a tree trunk with branches. the Alpha angle is the angle of the new generated branch with its parent's branch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Construct a parametrization of the circle $d$ in $3$ stages of increasing generality.

**1.**  Suppose that $B$ is the north pole (colatitude $\varphi = 0$).

The circle is the parallel (line of constant colatitude $\varphi = \alpha$), which has $z = \cos \alpha$ and $r = \sin \alpha$; hence, it is parametrized in rectangular coordinates by $t \mapsto \big( x(t), y(t), z(t) \big)$, where
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
x &= \sin \alpha \cos t \\
y &= \sin \alpha \sin t \\
z &= \cos \alpha
\end{align}
\right.
\qquad \text{for } 0 \le t < 2\pi.
$$

**2.**  Suppose that $B$ is on the prime meridian (longitude $\theta = 0$) but colatitude has some value $\varphi = \beta$, where $0 < \beta \le \pi$.

We take the coordinates $(x, y, z)$ of the circle with center at the north pole (from 1.) and rotate them through an angle $\beta$ along the great circle that includes the prime meridian.  Using [standard formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29) for rotating coordinates, we have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y \\ z
\end{bmatrix}
\mapsto
\begin{bmatrix}
x \cos \beta + z \sin \beta \\ y \\ -x \sin \beta + z \cos \beta
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

**3.**  Suppose that $B$ is anywhere on the sphere with spherical coordinates $(\varphi, \theta) = (\beta, \gamma)$.  Take the resulting coordinates from 2. and rotate them about the polar axis of the sphere through an angle of $\gamma$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y \\ z
\end{bmatrix}
\mapsto
\begin{bmatrix}
x \cos \gamma - y \sin \gamma \\ x \sin \gamma + y \cos \gamma \\ z
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Putting these together, the general case for a circle $d$ with center at $(\varphi, \theta) = (\beta, \gamma)$ and central angle $\alpha$ (that determines the radius) has rectangular coordinates:
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
x &= \phantom{-}( \sin \alpha \cos \beta \cos \gamma ) \cos t + ( \sin \alpha \sin \gamma ) \sin t - (\cos \alpha \sin \beta \cos \gamma ) \\
y &= -( \sin \alpha \cos \beta \sin \gamma ) \cos t + ( \sin \alpha \cos \gamma ) \sin t + (\cos \alpha \sin \beta \sin \gamma ) \\
z &= \phantom{-}( \sin \alpha \sin \beta ) \cos t + \cos \alpha \cos \beta.
\end{align}
\right.
$$

Comment: If you like the answer, then you should upvote it and select it, so the question is listed as answered.

Comment: I am sure your answer is perfect but I must be doing something wrong in my program...I get the circle but not around the segment from the center to B.

Comment: About a decade too late, but in case this helps anyone: I was coding this answer up and found the same result as @dargelos. I found I needed to replace $\gamma$ with $\gamma'=\pi-\gamma$ in the formulas above for the circle to be centered on $B$.

Answer (score 1):

By my math, the final result should be:

$$x = (\sinα\cosβ\cosγ)\cos t - (\sinα\sinγ)\sin t + (\cosα\sinβ\cosγ)$$

$$y =(\sinα\cosβ\sinγ)\cos t + (\sinα\cosγ)\sin t + (\cosα\sinβ\sinγ)$$

$$z = -(\sinα\sinβ)\cos t+\cosα\cosβ.$$