# Solvable equation for angle between points on a sphere?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, spheres, spherical-trigonometry

I'm looking for an equation that would give the coordinates (latitude $\delta$,longitude $\phi$) (on a sphere) for all the points on the surface of the sphere that have a certain angular distance $\Phi$ (angle centered on the center of the sphere) to a certain point of coordinates $\delta_0$,$\phi_0$.

Comment: See if this answer can help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2541378/lat-lon-coordinates-of-a-circle-on-a-sphere

Answer (score 0):

Start with $\delta_0=90°$ (north pole): in that case the circle of angular distance $\Phi$ has parametric equations
$$
\cases{
x=\cos t \sin \Phi, \\
y=\sin t \sin \Phi, \\
z=\cos \Phi.
}
$$
Perform then a rotation by $\pi/2-\delta_0$ about the $y$ axis, followed by a rotation by $\phi_0$ about the $z$ axis, to carry the center at latitude $\delta_0$ and longitude $\phi_0$. The parametric equations become:
$$
\cases{
x=\cos\phi_0 \cos\delta_0\cos\Phi+\sin\delta_0\cos t\sin\Phi-\sin t\sin\Phi\sin\phi_0,\\
y=\sin\phi_0\cos\delta_0\cos\Phi+\sin\delta_0\cos t\sin\Phi+\sin t\sin\Phi\cos\phi_0,\\
z=\sin\delta_0\cos\Phi-\cos\delta_0\cos t\sin\Phi.
}
$$
Comparing that with the standard polar coordinates
$$
\cases{
x=\cos\delta \cos\phi, \\
y=\cos\delta \sin \phi, \\
z=\sin\delta,
}
$$
one finally gets:
$$
\cases{
\sin\delta=\sin\delta_0\cos\Phi-\cos\delta_0\cos t\sin\Phi\\
\\
\cos\delta=\sqrt{\left(\cos \delta _0\cos\Phi+\sin\delta_0\cos t\sin\Phi\right)^2
+\sin^2t \sin^2\Phi}\\
\\
\sin\phi=\frac{\displaystyle
\sin\phi_0\cos\delta_0\cos\Phi+\sin\delta_0\cos t\sin\Phi+\sin t\sin\Phi\cos\phi_0}
{\displaystyle\sqrt{\left(\cos \delta _0\cos\Phi+\sin\delta_0\cos t\sin\Phi\right)^2
+\sin^2t \sin^2\Phi}}\\
\\
\cos\phi=\frac{\displaystyle
\cos\phi_0 \cos\delta_0\cos\Phi+\sin\delta_0\cos t\sin\Phi-\sin t\sin\Phi\sin\phi_0}
{\displaystyle\sqrt{\left(\cos \delta _0\cos\Phi+\sin\delta_0\cos t\sin\Phi\right)^2
+\sin^2t \sin^2\Phi}}\\
}
$$