# How to get all spherical angles $\phi$ and $\theta$, which describe a circle on a sphere?

Tags: geometry, polar-coordinates

I have a spherical rendering, where the spherical coordinates $\phi$ and $\theta$ are represented by the x and y axis of the image (similar to how world maps work):

[image]

Now given a point on the image with the pixel coordinates p($\phi$, $\theta$) I want to calculate the average color of all the neighboring pixels on the sphere within a radius (radius could maybe more easily be defined as an angle, since we are thinking of a unit sphere). For this I need to sum up all of the pixels within the circle, however the circle on the sphere will not be a circle on my map. So the question is, how can I get all the pixel coordinates (= my $\phi$ and $\theta$ angles) within the circle?

**Edit:**
Forgot to describe, how the rendering was done. With $\phi = [0, 2\pi]$ we divide $2\pi$ by the horizontal image resolution. $\theta = [0, \pi]$, so we divide $\pi$ by the vertical image resolution. Using a horizontal resolution that is twice the vertical resolution one pixel represents area on the sphere that is $(\frac{2 * \pi}{res_h}\times\frac{2 * \pi}{res_h})$.

Comment: This very much depends on how your sphere's surface has been mapped to a rectangle.  There are **many** [ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections) to do so and each provides different distortion of areas on the sphere.

Comment: @EricTowers sorry for the missing information, I will update the question immediately!

Comment: You image is roughly twice as wide as it is high, so your $x$-axis and $y$-axis may be longitude and latitude (with $0$ at the centre).  If so, it is worth knowing that, on a sphere, the length of a degree of latitude (north-south) does not vary while the length of a degree of longitude (east-west) is proportional to the cosine of the latitude and would may want to rescale your chosen pixels accordingly.

Comment: @Henry Yes I'm aware of that. Really though the map is just a visualization. In my actual application I have a function, where I plug in phi and theta and I get the corresponding color. Now given a certain phi and theta I want to average color within an area. Question is: which ranges of phi and theta do I need to use

Comment: If you want an average that is a valid average by area over the sphere, you also need to assign each pixel a weighting factor, because pixels nearer to the poles actually represent smaller parts of the sphere than pixels near the equator.

Comment: @RolandDeschain Since you said " a circle on a sphere" 3 parameters are required in general for spheres of small circles θ,ϕ,i ...where the last one is an extra inclination of the small circle to the great one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will stick to your notations $\phi$ for longitude, $\theta$ for latitude, although one finds rather often the inverse convention.

Given: a center $M_0$ (defined by spherical coordinates $(\phi_0,\theta_0)$) and a radius $R$ ($0<R<\pi/2$, measured as an arc on the unit sphere).

The set of points $M$ of the sphere which are interior to the spherical disk with center $M_0$ and radius $R$ is given by the following dot product constraint:

$$\vec{OM}.\vec{OM_0}>\cos(R)$$

which is equivalent, using classical spherical coordinates, to:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta)\\ \sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)\\ \sin(\theta)\end{pmatrix} .\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\phi_0)\cos(\theta_0)\\ \sin(\phi_0)\cos(\theta_0)\\ \sin(\theta_0)\end{pmatrix}>\cos(R)\tag{1}$$

This constraint can be written under the form:

$$\cos(\theta_0)\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi-\phi_0)+\sin(\theta_0)\sin(\theta)>\cos(R)\tag{2}$$

which is an implicit equation in $(\phi,\theta)$ depending upon three parameters $(\phi_0,\theta_0,R)$  that can be visualized with this Geogebra animation (play with the sliders !):

https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/eanc7njp

The top sliders $f$ and $t$ refer to the coordinates $\phi_0$ and $\theta_0$ resp. of center $M_0$.

Here are two examples:

[image]

*Fig. 1: An "ordinary" circle centered in (0,0) with radius $\pi/4$ rendered as a kind of ellipse.*

[image]

*Fig. 2: A "limit case" image of a circle belonging to northern hemisphere, tangent to the equator, (almost) passing throughout North Pole, explaining the almost linear segment ranging approximately from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$.*

**Remark 1:** constraint (1) has been given in the same form by @blamocur.

**Remark 2:** formula (2) could have been obtained directly by using the [spherical law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines)..

**Remark 3:** *Explicit* equations of the circle can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/643255).

Comment: I have a little improved my presentation done yesterday (axes' ticks in radians, etc. and also Remark 3). Any comment ?

Comment: Sorry, I commented  at a wrong place.

Comment: Sorry for the late replies, I'm a bit behind before being able to test the answers out. I will definitely check the answers and tag them :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be the axis of the circle passing through its center, and let $\theta_0$ be the angle of the radius (i.e. $\text{radius} =  \sin \theta_0$ )

The $a$ axis has coordinates:

$a = ( \sin \theta_a \cos \phi_a, \sin \theta_a \sin \phi_a, \cos \theta_a)$

you have to find two orthogonal vectors that are orthogonal to $a$, and these
can be chosen as follows:

$u_1 = ( \cos \theta_a \cos \phi_a, \cos \theta_a \sin \phi_a , - \sin \theta_a )$

$u_2 = (- \sin \phi_a,  \cos \phi_a , 0 )$

The rectangular coordinates of points at the circular region boundary are given by (with respect to the basis $[u_1, u_2, a]$, utilizing the respective spherical coordinates) are:

$(x', y', z') =  ( \sin \theta_0 \cos \phi, \sin \theta_0 \sin \phi, \cos \theta_0 )$

where $0 \le \phi \le 2 \pi $

now the world rectangular coordinates of the circular region boundary is

$(x, y, z) = [u_1, u_2, a] (x', y', z') = x' u_1 + y' u_2 + z' a$

once you've calculated $(x, y, z)$ , you can calculate the corresponding $\theta, \phi$ in the original world coordinates, as follows

$ \theta = \cos^{-1} (z)$ and $ \phi = \text{atan2} (x, y) $

By changing $\phi$ over $[0, 2 \pi]$ you get a closed curve in your image, that encloses all the pixels you want.

Comment: Thank you this looks good. I guess I only have to divide up the range to get numerical results, but I'll test this out and mark the answer (prolly until tomorrow :) ). Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want a neighborhood of a point on a unit square given by angles $\phi_0,\theta_0$ and "angle-radius" $\rho$. We'll assume that the neighborhood does not contain the poles, i.e. $\rho \leq \theta_0 \leq \pi$. You neighborhood can then be described by this inequality:

$$ \langle \mathbf v_{\phi_0,\theta_0}
\cdot
 \mathbf v_{\phi,\theta} \rangle
 \geq \cos \rho
$$

where $\mathbf v_{\phi,\theta}$ is the unit vector with spheric coordinates $\phi,\theta$, and $\langle\cdot\rangle$ denotes dot product.  In practice you can scan all points in the $[\phi_0-\rho, \phi_0+\rho] \times [\theta_0-\rho, \theta_0+\rho] $ spheric rectangle and use the above inequality to check whether they belong to the circular area.

Alternately, you can use an equivalent inequality:
$$ ||\mathbf v_{\phi,\theta}-\mathbf v_{\phi_0,\theta_0}||^2 
\leq 4\sin^2 \frac{\rho}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Any circle on a sphere can be obtained as the intersection with a plane. Hence in spherical coordinates, the constraint will be

$$a\cos\theta\sin\phi+b\sin\theta\sin\phi+c\cos\phi=d$$

where $(a,b,c)$ correspond to the normal vector and is also the coordinates of the given point. $d$ is the cosine of the aperture angle of the cone generated by the circle, the radius of which is the sine.

---

With the point given in spherical coordinates,
$$\sin\Phi\cos(\theta-\Theta)\sin\phi+\cos\Phi\cos\phi=\sqrt{1-r^2}$$